# How to get image to ignore parent div padding?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that is contained inside of of "article". Article has a padding of 1.2em.

```
article,
nav,
div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #061621;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

The CSS that I have for the image is as follows:

```
.shipImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

As a result, the padding is applied to the image, resulting in the display shown below:

[image]

I have indicted with red arrows where I would like the image to stretch to. I have tried setting a margin of -1.2em on the image, but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use:

```css
.shipImage {
  width: calc(100% + (1.2em * 2));
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to structure your HTML/CSS as followed (one color = one class):[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin with minus value

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and it kept me awake for days until I stumbled upon this solution. I am not sure if the link is still active, so I am just going to share the code:

```
.span_padding {
  
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -50vw;
   margin-right: -50vw;
   max-width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   right: 50%;
   width: 100vw;


}
```

Then apply the class `.span_padding` to your image